# The Book of Numbers and Passover

Tags: passover, calendar, pentateuch-chumash

Why is LORD'S passover (Numbers 28:16) on the fourteenth day of the first month?

Comment: Welcome.  I think I know where you want to go with this, but you should know that, in my experience, Christian commentaries on the differences between Passover beginning on the 14th or the 15th of Nisan are based on a confusion of the texts.  Numbers 28:16 is quite correct that the Passover festival -- which involved the slaughter of the Passover lambs in the Temple -- occurred on the 14th.  The Festival of Matzahs, which included the eating of the Passover lamb and the telling of the story, began on the 15th.

Answer (score 4):

On the 14th, during the desert and temple times, there was a "paschal offering to God" on the 14th and the holiday began soon after. For a chronology which explains how the time in Egypt for recognizing God's dominion began on the 10th of the month, check out Exodus 12:3 through 12:11. The sacrifice, timed by God in Exodus to coincide with the plague on the first-born of Egypt, was institutionalized on that date for later years, as Numbers explains.